# clone a div from parent to modal and then append div on modal to a div in parent html using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, innerhtml, appendchild

I am trying to have a DIV inside my HTML open as a modal window.

My HTML looks as follows:

```
<div class='divHeading' id='configurations'>
    <div class='divDisplay' id='array'>
        <div class='divHeading'>
            <h4 class='plus' data-ng-click='hide($event)'>
                Configuration
                 <input type='submit' name='disable' value='Disable'
                    data-ng-click='disable($event)' class='add-regular  pull-right'>
                 <input type='submit' name='update' value='Update'
                    data-ng-click='update($event)' class='add-regular pull-right'>
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On click of **update** , modal opens and copies the div to modal, this copy works fine, the js for controller is :

```
var TestController = function($scope, $window, $http, $routeParams, $sce,
        $compile, $ocModal) {
    $scope.update = function(updateClicked) {
        var currentConfInnerHTML = updateClicked.target.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
        var configurationsDiv = updateClicked.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
        $compile(currentConfInnerHTML)($scope);
        $ocModal.open({
            url : 'partials/TestConfigurationModal.html',
            controller : 'modalController',
            cls : 'fade-in',
            init : {
                currentConf : currentConfInnerHTML,
                confDiv : configurationsDiv
            }
        });

        $scope.disable = function(disableClicked) {
            alert("Disable Clicked");
            disableClicked.stopPropagation();
        };
}
```

The template code is :

```
     <script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/TestConfigurationModal.html">
           <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="closeModal()">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Clone Configuration</h4>
           </div>
           <div id="copyConf" class="divHeading">
           </div>
           <input type='submit' name='update' value='Update' data-ng-click='addCloneToMainConfig($event)' id='btn'>

 </script>
```

The controller for modal is :

```
var modalController = function($scope, $window, $http, $routeParams, $sce,
        $compile, $ocModal, $init) {
    html_code = $init.currentConf;
    document.getElementById('copyConf').innerHTML = html_code;
    $compile(document.getElementById('copyConf'))($scope);

    $scope.addCloneToMainConfig = function(u) {
        var new_row = document.getElementById('copyConf');
        var con = document.getElementById('configurations');
        con.childNodes[1].appendChild(new_row);
        $compile(document.getElementById('configurations'))($scope);
    };
}
```

The div is also successfully appended to parent html div, but the buttons of newly appended child does not work.

I have tried compiling both the divs , but failed.

I am badly stuck and really need help. Please guide through this.